# libsmbclient documentation

Tags: samba

I am trying to implement a remote file system and was thinking of using the libsmbclient
to do that. Unfortunately, I have not come across any useful documentation when googleling for
it. Could anyone advice me where the API of the libsmbclient is described in some detail?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can download the documentation from this link:

https://sites.google.com/site/adnankamili/

It has been created using doxygen.

Answer (score 3):

What, [man 7 libsmbclient](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/libsmbclient.7.html) isn't enough?  :)

Samba's has Doxygen API documentation, but it looks like the automated document generation and publishing on samba.org is broken.  If you grab the sources yourself, you can run <kbd>`doxygen source/Doxyfile`</kbd> to generate a local copy of the documentation, outputting to `dox/`.

Comment: Your link to man page is useless (at least currently). It describes only smb://  url parts. It doesn't contain any API info.

Comment: @KonstantinGribov, it's called sarcasm... surprised you haven't seen it more often to recognize it.

Comment: @Ioan, it seems to me that doxygen generated "documentation" is called documentation without sarcasm in both answers above. As a matter of fact doxygen documentation lacks descriptions for some methods from `libsmbclient.h`. So, the only way to understand how it work is to download samba source and take a look into `source3/libsmb/` (as of 4.3.x). Also `examples` are worth looking through them at least.

Comment: @KonstantinGribov, lol, the sarcasm was the first line in this answer. The manpage is very short and practically useless; hence the sarcasm in it "not being enough"... It has nothing to do with the doxygen documentation, which is commonly used to document libraries.

Comment: @Ioan, I mean, doxygen for libsmbclient (not doxygen itself) is not very usefull too. It contains a lot of copy-pasted comments, some crucial things aren't mentioned, so real documentation is library source and its examples.

Answer (score 1):

[fossies.org](https://fossies.org) currently hosts a copy of the documentation (generated by Doxygen) for several versions of the Samba suite, which includes `libsmbclient`. At the time of writing, documentation is available for Samba versions 4.15.8 and 4.16.2 – look under https://fossies.org/samba to select a version, then follow the "Fossies services: [Doxygen documentation](https://fossies.org/dox/samba-4.15.8/)" link to get to the API documentation.

Documentation for the `libsmbclient` API can be found from the top-level pages of one of these versions by looking under "Modules" / "Libsmbclient". The data structures don't seem to be documented at all, but the functions do at least have (fairly minimal) documentation.

To see how the functions are to be used, the best place to look seems to be in the "examples" directory of the Samba source tree – take a look at https://github.com/samba-team/samba/tree/master/examples/libsmbclient, where you'll find small test programs which exercise bits of the `libsmbclient` API.